# Soft delete laravel : page does not exist or hard delete

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I have a problem with sofdelete in Laravel .. 
In my destroy method :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $sessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('id','=', $id);
    $sessions->delete();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'it works !');
    return redirect()->route('sessions.index');
}
```

it doesn't make a soft delete ... 
If i change the request using eloquent :

```
    $sessions = Sessions::findOrFail($id);
    $sessions->delete();
```

I have : Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

In my view I created the form

```
{!! Form::open([
        'method' => 'DELETE',
        'route' => ['sessions.destroy', $session->id]
]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('delete?', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work... 
thanks for your help

Comment: Look in your database. The record should have a "deleted_at" date and because it has one, it will be "soft deleted" and excluded from the module

Comment: I have a deleted_at date in my DB .. that's why i'm wondering ...

Comment: Sorry, just re-read, You are not using a model, you are making a more direct database request with `\DB::whatever()`. You need to use your `Sessions::findOrFail()->delete()` to soft delete as this uses the model functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that when you're using `DB::table('sessions')` it deletes the record and when you're using `Sessions::` it doesn't

I think you don't understand what soft deleting is.

When you use `DB::table('sessions')`, the record will be just deleted and not soft deleted.

When you use `Session::`, the record will stay there but Eloquent will add `deleted_at` timestamp.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting):

> When models are soft deleted, they are not actually removed from your database. Instead, a `deleted_at` attribute is set on the model and inserted into the database. If a model has a non-null `deleted_at` value, the model has been soft deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Session is facade of laravel so it might be create issue for you. please refer following link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session